# Filtering in nested array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a nested data structure mapped to array in knockout JS:

```
class Departments{
     string DepartmentName;
     List<Group> groups
}
class Group{
     string groupName;
     List<Person> persons;
}
class Person{
     String Firsname;
     string LastName;
}
```

I fetched data from server and show them in UI successfully. But I want convert the array to a computed one in knockoutJS and filter it by `FirstName` and `LastName`. It's worthy to mention I have bound `self.search_FirstName and self.search_LastName` to two different inputs. HTML code for binding data is as follow:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="text-right text-success input-lg" placeholder="Name" data-bind="value:search_FirstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />    
</div>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: Profiles" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title" data-bind="text: DepartmentName"></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table data-bind="foreach: { data: GroupVMs }" class="table table-responsive col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td class="groups" data-bind="text: GroupName"></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table data-bind="foreach: { data: PersonPhonesVMs }" class="table table-striped table-responsive col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1" data-bind="text: Prefix"></td>
                                        <td class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
                                        <td class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>                                        
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want during typing in the  text box `search_FirstName` data automatically be filtered. Right Now I can filter records based on `DepartmentName` with the following code:

```
self.Profiles = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.BackupProfiles(), function (rec) {
            return (
                (self.search_FirstName().length == 0 || rec.DepartmentName.indexOf(self.search_FirstName()) > -1)
            );
        });
    });
```

Does anyone has any idea for filtering records based on firstname and lastname fields?

Comment: Your current code makes little sense to me. Why are you comparing `DepartmentName` with `search_FirstName`, those are two different things no? Why are you using `indexOf` and not `localeCompare`? What is the actual problem with the *task* you posed in your last sentence? Can't you just go ahead and do it? Please try to update your question with a more complete example.

Comment: PS. I've replaced the "asp.net-mvc" tag with "javascript". I realize the first bit of code currently is c#, but I'd highly recommend changing it to the javascript for your app since the question otherwise seemed to have little to do with server side code. If this was a mistake feel free to rollback the tag edit, but if so please also clarify how "asp.net-mvc" is relevant to the question.

Comment: I want to show that I can search by the first level but cannot go ahead to search in inner levels. comparing search_FirstName and departmentName has not any sense.

Comment: @Jeroen In the first place I get the whole data from server which is implemented by ASP.Net.

Comment: Sure, you get the data from ASP.NET. But would your problem change or disappear if the back-end was PHP or localStorage? From your question I guess not. It would be a lot easier for us to help you if you eliminate having to deal with the server side tech, and make a repro for just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag2z1vsw/) for you. The `computed` at the heart of it builds up a structure like the Profiles structure, but only including the matched records.

```
vm.filteredProfiles = ko.computed(function () {
    var first = vm.search_FirstName().toLocaleLowerCase();
    if (first === '') return vm.Profiles();
    var result = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.Profiles(), function (dept) {
        var groupsMatched = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(dept.GroupVMs(), function (group) {
            var personsMatched = [];
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(group.PersonPhonesVMs(), function (person) {
                if (person.FirstName().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(first) > -1) {
                    personsMatched.push(person);
                }
            });
            if (personsMatched.length > 0) {
                groupsMatched.push({
                    GroupName: group.GroupName,
                    PersonPhonesVMs: personsMatched
                });
            }
        });
        if (groupsMatched.length > 0) {
            result.push({
                DepartmentName: dept.DepartmentName,
                GroupVMs: groupsMatched
            });
        }
    });

    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to "flatten" the entire structure, so that you have an array of people with with DepartmentName and GroupName fields. For the `computed` to work, each level of your original structure must be `observableArrays`. The computed would be something like:

```
var flattenedPeople = ko.computed(function () {
  var result = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.BackupProfiles(), function (dept) {
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(dept.groups(), function (group) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(group.persons(), function (person) {
          result.push({
            DepartmentName: dept.DepartmentName,
            GroupName: group.GroupName,
            FirstName: person.FirstName,
            LastName: person.LastName
        });
      });
    });
  return result;
});
```

Then you could make a computed that would match on FirstName and/or Lastname:

```
self.filteredPeople = ko.computed(function () {
  var first = self.search_FirstName(),
      last = self.search_LastName();
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(flattenedPeople(), function (rec) {
    return ( first === '' || rec.FirstName === first ) &&
      (last === '' || rec.LastName === last );
  });
});
```

Comment: You could probably improve the actual search conditions to something like `!first || rec.FirstName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(first) > -1`.

Comment: @Roy J: thanks!!! but i don't want to flatten the whole array. I want keep the structure as is and search for persons by their name. finally remove all departments and/or groups which have not any matching person.

Comment: You don't lose the original structure by having the computeds. You can use `filteredPeople` in another computed to filter Departments and Groups. Build up the tools you need. If you include the HTML and how you want it to work, I can give you more specific help.

Comment: @Joy J I have augmented the question by adding HTML code as well. please help me!!!